# Why can't REST resource methods have the final modifier when using JAX-RS?

Tags: rest, methods, cxf, jax-rs, final

We are using CXF 2.4.2 to create a RESTful interface. I have a bean resource class that is defined as follows:

```
@Path("/mypath")
public class MyResource {

    @GET
    @Path("/myget")
    public final Response myGet() { ... }
```

Does anyone know why the method can't be final in order to access the resource?

Comment: I've added a final modifier to a Jersey-annotated method, and it works as before. Something about CXF maybe?

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes JAX-RS is implemented in such a way, that instead of original class (that we create) JAX-RS is using proxy class which inherits from our class. Since final method cannot be overriden, usage of final methods is prohibited.

Usage of proxy enables adding to JAX-RS framework various interceptors, providers, etc. Obviously the same functionality can be obtain without using proxy, so other providers might allow usage of final methods.

The specification does not say anything about final methods.

Side note: very often usage of final method is a bad idea. Sometimes even if we think that given method should not be overriden, it may appear that is necessary. Even Java creators made a few such mistakes. Obviously there are classes, which methods should not be overriden (String), but there are not a lot of them.